# Android Django connection through WSGI

Tags: android, django

I am trying to access django project (mysite) on my android virtual device.
Content of **/var/www/mysite/apache** django.wsgi file is:

```
import os
import sys
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www')
sys.path.insert(1,'/var/www/mysite')
sys.path.insert(1,'/var/www/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

My `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file:

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 1
ServerName localhost
PythonPath "['/var/www','/var/www/mysite','/var/www/mysite/books','/var/www/templates'] + sys.path"
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
<Location "/mysite/">
SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
    PythonOption django.root /mysite
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost` file:

```
<Virtualhost 192.168.1.2:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite    
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
</Virtualhost>
```

Now when I try to access `url="http://192.168.1.2/mysite/login"` in android avd it is giving me the following error:

```
 "error Cannot connect to destination (192.168.1.2)"
```

I am able to access the site by typing `"http://localhost/mysite/login"` in browser but not in android avd.

Can anyone help me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host computer (the one running the emulator) is available on the virtual Android device using `10.0.2.2` IP and **not** using the actual IP of the PC.

See the [emulator networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) reference.

Comment: the problem was got solved when i accesed the url by my system ip...in my lappy the ip wasnt set so i just set the ip and the problem was solved

Comment: The problem was with ip. i just executed the command "sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0" to set eth0 ip.
and then gave 10.0.0.10 in my url and got it to run